# discord.js List channels with a certain role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Trying to find a way to add into my bot, if someone types for example +info
it will list all the channels on the server with a certain role. 
So if the role is VIP, doing +info would list every channel on the server which has the role VIP.

Have been trying to read the doc's but can't find anything that shows what I want. I'm guessing it would have to use a different module.
Can any one help with this?
Cheers

Comment: whay do you mean by "with a certain role" ? The role of the user typing +info ?

Comment: if a channel as a role VIP set under it. it will list that channel when asked. So if someone types '+info' it displays

VIP users have access to the following channels.
-#vip-chat
-#vip-users
etc....

if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all the channels in the guild and check whether the User has the `VIEW_CHANNEL` permission, to check if they have access to the channel. Perhaps something like this:

```
const listedChannels = []; 
message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => { 
    if(channel.permissionsFor(message.author).has('VIEW_CHANNEL')) listedChannels.push(channel.name);
});
message.channel.send(`You have access to: ${listedChannels.join(',')}`);
```

What this does, is it iterates through the collection of channels in the guild and if the author of the message has permissions to actually view the channel, then it will add that channel name to the array. Then, it sends a message saying a list of channels the user has access to.

Comment: Thanks, Works. Just need to fix over 2000 char limit. But works as intended.

Comment: @JustinJones You might want to look into the `split` option https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions. Please accept my answer if you feel like it solved your problem.